# Proper way for adding a "Summary" or "Bottom Line" in the Beginning of a Sentence

Tags: word-usage, sentence

I'm struggling to find the right way to address my audience in starting of my course description page with a go to the point Summary,

i'm not sure how to express whats in my mind but this is an Example :

Hi

Blah Blah Blah, Max two Sentence

**Summary :
or Bottom Line :**

**! This is the problem !**

i don't think these are the right words !

and things like lets get into it right know or lets get to the point seem childish !

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's incredibly unclear what your actual question is: can you refine it please?

Comment: i was looking for something more formal than TLDR and our friend answered it.... BLUF!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In business and civil service, this is known as a [BLUF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLUF_(communication)) (bottom line up front). So you might begin with the bold text **BLUF:** followed by your summary, but only if you expect your audience to be familiar with this.

It sounds like you're trying to keep things relatively formal, but if you weren't, [TL;DR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR) (too long; didn't read) is common in online forums.